# How to list directory using Python

Tags: python, list, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to list all files of a directory in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207219/how-to-list-all-files-of-a-directory-in-python)

How do I list all directory content using python and add it to a list?

Answer (score 6):

With Python, there so many ways to do this however, this one is the simplest i know.

Please check the comments for the specifics of the output.

```
from os import listdir
list = listdir("C:\Users\Hello\World\Python Programs")
print list #Outputs the whole list
print len(list) #Checks for the length of the list
print list[26] #Outputs a specific element in the list
```

Good luck!

Comment: Might want to be careful with backslashes in paths as they conflict with string escape characters.

Comment: Therefore, put "r" before the string: `list = listdir(r"C:\Users\Hello\World\Python Programs")`

Comment: Umm... answering your own question is encouraged if you figure out the answer in the meantime, but... why are you acting as if you're two people? (e.g., w/ "Good luck!")

Comment: @MuMind, well, the good luck is just an expression which shouldn't be a matter to how the question is answered. :) if you want, you can edit the answer and remove it. :)